# Decrease the website loading time in cypress

Tags: cypress

When I run my test in Cypress, it takes about 15 - 18 sec to start loading the page. Is there no way to solve this issue to decrease the time? Seems like Cypress itself requires such time to configure something, because to load the webpage itself takes no more than 2 sec.

To start loading the website takes ~16 sec

```
context('Actions', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'))
    })
```

Cypress version: 8.2.0

Comment: Do you see any failures ?

Comment: No there are no failures, I built the project locally and run tests on http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Use ctr-shft-i and check the performance tab.